# Quickbooks SDK 13.0 ToDoAddRq C#

Tags: c#, quickbooks

hey guys i'm new to this sdk i'm trying to add TODO every thing is fine till i'm trying to specify time or Priority or type it is giving me error
**"QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream"**
i'm using SDK 13
can any one help me please
thank you

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using QBFC13Lib;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace testing
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool sessionBegun = false;
        bool connectionOpen = false;
        QBSessionManager sessionManager = null;

        try
        {
            sessionManager = new QBSessionManager();

            //Create the message set request object to hold our request
            IMsgSetRequest requestMsgSet = sessionManager.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 8, 0);
            requestMsgSet.Attributes.OnError = ENRqOnError.roeContinue;

            //Connect to QuickBooks and begin a session
            sessionManager.OpenConnection("", "QuickBook Account Import");
            connectionOpen = true;
            sessionManager.BeginSession("C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Intuit\\QuickBooks\\Company Files\\***.qbw", ENOpenMode.omDontCare);
            sessionBegun = true;



                IToDoAdd ToDoAddRq = requestMsgSet.AppendToDoAddRq();
                ToDoAddRq.ReminderDate.SetValue(DateTime.ParseExact("29/4/2014", "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                //Set field value for Time
                ToDoAddRq.ReminderTime.SetValue(10, 10, 10, false);
                //Set field value for Notes
                ToDoAddRq.Notes.SetValue("abc");
                //Set field value for IsActive
                ToDoAddRq.IsActive.SetValue(true);
                //Set field value for Type
                ToDoAddRq.Type_2.SetValue(ENType.tCall);
                //Set field value for Priority
                ToDoAddRq.Priority.SetValue(ENPriority.pLow);


                //Send the request and get the response from QuickBooks
                sessionManager.DoRequests(requestMsgSet);


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
        }
        finally
        {
            //End the session and close the connection to QuickBooks
            if (sessionBegun)
            {
                sessionManager.EndSession();
            }
            if (connectionOpen)
            {
                sessionManager.CloseConnection();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What version of qbXML are you using?

Comment: i'm not using qbXML
i'm using QBFC13Lib
thank you for your time

Comment: Yes, you are. :-)  QBFC is just a wrapper around qbXML. You're likely still setting the qbXML version somewhere. Post the rest of your code.

Comment: this is my whole code
thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The QuickBooks qbXML API is a *versioned* API. Different versions of QuickBooks will support different functionality via different versions of the qbXML spec.

When developing, you need to make sure you're using a version of the qbXML API that both supports the functionality you need, and that your version of QuickBooks supports.

You are currently using qbXML version `8.0`:

```
 IMsgSetRequest requestMsgSet = sessionManager.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 8, 0);
```

Typically, QuickBooks versions are 1 off from the qbXML version supports. e.g. QuickBooks 14 supports qbXML version 13. QuickBooks 13 supports qbXML version 12. etc. That means that right now you're targeting QuickBooks 2009.

You're getting an error message because, if you refer to [Intuit's docs](https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html), `ToDoAdd`s `Type` and `Priority` tags are only supported in version `13.0` and higher. You need to either not include those values in your request, or use a higher qbXML API version.

Comment: yes now i understood tha problem
thank you i'm gonna check this and see how to solve the problem