# Is there a limit on the amount of Quickbooks report query requests at one time?

Tags: c#, quickbooks, qbfc

Is there a limit to the amount of report queries that can be added/returned from a `MsgSetRequest` at one time in QBFC?

I'm currently creating and adding multiple `GeneralSummaryReportQuery`'s to the `MsgSetRequest` (say 30), but after I do the requests things seem to go wrong.  I can see the `ResponseList` being the correct size, but after the first 10 `Response`'s in the list, the status code for the remaining responses changes to `3320` which indicates that the report cannot be generated.  If I run the same report with the same filters with less queries added to the request, the report is successfully generated.

I've looked through the QBSDK ProGuide book as well as done some googling, but I haven't seen anything online that mention this limitation.

Here's some sample code for what it's worth:

```
IMsgSetRequest msgSetReq = sessionManager.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 13, 0);
msgSetReq.Attributes.OnError = ENRqOnError.roeContinue;
foreach (string key in traversalOrder) {
    IGeneralSummaryReportQuery summaryReportQuery = msgSetReq.AppendGeneralSummaryReportQueryRq();
    summaryReportQuery.GeneralSummaryReportType.SetValue(ENGeneralSummaryReportType.gsrtProfitAndLossByJob);
    summaryReportQuery.ReportEntityFilter.ORReportEntityFilter.FullNameList.Add(tableData[key].FullName);
}

//Now do all the queries
IMsgSetResponse msgSetResp = sessionManager.DoRequests(msgSetReq);

for (int k = 0; k < msgSetResp.ResponseList.Count; k++) {
    IResponse resp = msgSetResp.ResponseList.GetAt(k);

    if (resp.StatusCode >= 0 && resp.Detail != null) {
        //do stuff -- this only enters in the first 10 Responses in the ResponseList
    }
}
```

I enabled verbose logging and looked into the logs - the report requests are being generated as expected in XML format:

```
<GeneralSummaryReportQueryRq requestID = "9">
<GeneralSummaryReportType>ProfitAndLossByJob</GeneralSummaryReportType>
<ReportEntityFilter>
<FullName>TestGuy9</FullName>
</ReportEntityFilter>
</GeneralSummaryReportQueryRq>

<GeneralSummaryReportQueryRq requestID = "10">
<GeneralSummaryReportType>ProfitAndLossByJob</GeneralSummaryReportType>
<ReportEntityFilter>
<FullName>TestGuy10</FullName>
</ReportEntityFilter>
</GeneralSummaryReportQueryRq>
```

However, further down in the logs we see the report generation fail, but no indication as to why.  This continues for any remaining report requests that follow.

```
20190919.103424 I   16112   QBSDKMsgSetHandler  QUERY: General Summary Report
20190919.103424 D   16112   ReportStorage::DoQuery  Processing request for report: ProfitAndLossByJob
20190919.103424 D   16112   ReportStorage::DoQuery  Setting report type
20190919.103424 D   16112   ReportStorage::DoQuery  Initializing report defaults
20190919.103424 D   16112   ReportStorage::DoQuery  1st override of defaults
20190919.103424 D   16112   ReportStorage::DoQuery  Initializing report
20190919.103424 D   16112   ReportStorage::DoQuery  2nd override of defaults
20190919.103424 D   16112   ReportStorage::DoQuery  Generating the report
20190919.103425 D   16112   ReportStorage::DoQuery  Building the response
20190919.103425 D   16112   ReportHandler::BuildTheRetObject    Number of column rows: 2
20190919.103425 D   16112   ReportStorage::DoQuery  Finished building the response
20190919.103425 I   16112   QBSDKMsgSetHandler  Request 9 completed successfully.
20190919.103425 I   16112   QBSDKMsgSetHandler  QUERY: General Summary Report
20190919.103425 D   16112   ReportStorage::DoQuery  Processing request for report: ProfitAndLossByJob
20190919.103425 D   16112   ReportStorage::DoQuery  Setting report type
20190919.103425 D   16112   ReportStorage::DoQuery  Initializing report defaults
20190919.103425 D   16112   ReportStorage::DoQuery  1st override of defaults
20190919.103425 D   16112   ReportStorage::DoQuery  Initializing report
20190919.103425 D   16112   ReportStorage::DoQuery  2nd override of defaults
20190919.103425 D   16112   ReportStorage::DoQuery  Generating the report
20190919.103425 E   16112   ReportHandler::GenerateReport   Unable to generate the report
20190919.103425 I   16112   QBSDKMsgSetHandler  Request 10 failed.
```

Comment: Open Task Manager and check memory usage while code runs.  You may have a memory leak.

Comment: I don't know whether there is a limit, but since it seems to work for the first 10, as a workaround you could try running your query in batches of 10 and then combine the results manually.

Comment: @jdweng I don't think memory is the issue - I kept task manager open while I ran my queries, and while Quickbooks RAM usage did increase, I never went above 75% memory total (including all processes).  Visual Studio had the memory usage for my application at about 200MB (peak).  

@Kei I could certainly run them in batch and was planning to do that as a backup. :)  Was just wondering if there was a reason why the reports stopped coming back in after more than 10 queries in one `MsgSetRequest`.

Comment: I don't know if this link will help but it is worth reading : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23343880/quickbooks-sdk-13-0-todoaddrq-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out a way to condense the multiple reports I wanted into one large report, but this is a workaround and won't always be a possible solution.

It seems that there is a 10 report limit per response, so the solution here would be to do the reports in batches of 10.  If anyone finds out something otherwise, I'll be happy to mark it as the correct answer.